# Read XMLDocument with same Element names

Tags: vb.net

I have to read XML document data which is here:

```
<root>
  <cartype>Mercedes</cartype>
  <production>2005</production>
  <fuel>Diesel</fuel>
  <color>Red</color>
  <services>
    <service>
      <year>2006</year>
      <km>47800</km>
      <city>Stuttgart</city>
    </service>
    <service>
      <year>2007</year>
      <km>92125</km>
      <city>FFM</city>
    </service>
    <service>
      <km>180420</km>
      <year>2009</year>
      <city>Hannover</city>
    </service>
  </services>
  <condition>Good</condition>
</root>
```

Then I read it as such:

```
Dim cartype As String
Dim fuel As String
Dim production As String
Dim color As String
Dim serviceyear() As String = {"", "", ""}
Dim servicekm() As String = {"", "", ""}
Dim sevicecity() As String = {"", "", ""}
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

doc.Load("mercedes.xml")
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement

Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("production")
If Not node Is Nothing Then production = node.InnerText

node = root.SelectSingleNode("cartype")
If Not node Is Nothing Then cartype = node.InnerText

node = root.SelectSingleNode("fuel")
If Not node Is Nothing Then fuel = node.InnerText

node = root.SelectSingleNode("color")
If Not node Is Nothing Then color = node.InnerText

node = root.SelectSingleNode("services/service/year") '' first service year
If Not node Is Nothing Then serviceyear(0) = node.InnerText

node = root.SelectSingleNode("services/service/year") '' second service year
If Not node Is Nothing Then serviceyear(1) = node.InnerText
```

Reading nodes with unique element names is OK but I don't know how to read all "services" in array since showed code reads only first service. Services may be from 0 to undefined number of it. Function have to be as fast is possible since large number of xml's have to be readed in what is possible less time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a variable number of `<service>` elements you will need to use `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode`:

```
Dim services = root.SelectNodes("services/service")
```

You can then iterate over the `<service>` nodes:

```
For Each service In services
    If service("year") IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim year = service("year").InnerText
    End If
Next
```

Personally, I would use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb387098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to parse the file (but that may be because I am obsessed with all things LINQ!).  Combined with VB.NET's support for [XML Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) it makes for some really nice looking code (IMHO).

Here is a complete example you can paste into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

```
Sub Main
    ' Use XElememt.Load(fileName) to load from file
    Dim xml =
    <root>
        <cartype>Mercedes</cartype>
        <production>2005</production>
        <fuel>Diesel</fuel>
        <color>Red</color>
        <services>
            <service>
                <year>2006</year>
                <km>47800</km>
                <city>Stuttgart</city>
            </service>
            <service>
                <year>2007</year>
                <km>92125</km>
                <city>FFM</city>
            </service>
            <service>
                <km>180420</km>
                <year>2009</year>
                <city>Hannover</city>
            </service>
        </services>
        <condition>Good</condition>
    </root>
    Dim history = New ServiceHistory() With {
        .CarType = xml.<cartype>.Value,
        .Production = xml.<production>.Value,
        .Fuel = xml.<fuel>.Value,
        .Color = xml.<color>.Value,
        .Condition = xml.<condition>.Value,
        .Services = (
            From svc In xml.<services>.<service>
            Select New Service() With {
                .Year = svc.<year>.Value,
                .KM = svc.<km>.Value,
                .City = svc.<city>.Value
            }
        ).ToList()
    }
    history.Dump()
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
Public Class ServiceHistory
    Public Property CarType As String
    Public Property Production As String
    Public Property Fuel As String
    Public Property Color As String
    Public Property Condition As String
    Public Property Services As List(Of Service)
End Class

Public Class Service
    Public Property Year As String
    Public Property KM As String
    Public Property City As String
End Class
```

This gives you the following:

[image: LINQPad Results]

Comment: Thank you Mark for very educational answer and workable, handy solution. I prefer oldfashion way and it work nice. Just have to change this line: "For Each service As XmlNode In services" probably because Option Strict turned on.

Comment: Glad it was useful.  For the `As XmlNode` part, I always have `Option Infer On` and `Option Strict On` just to avoid a little typing while keeping the strict typing, so I'm always forgetting to be explicit in examples - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try linq it will be easier to parse the xml:
It have to be something like that:

```
xelement = XElement.Load(file);
services = xelement.Element("services").Elements("service");
```